# ORA-00920 - Sql exception when performing a Javers' query in ORACLE PL/SQL

Tags: spring-boot, plsql, javers

An exception is thrown whenever I try to execute a Javers JQL query. By example:

**The query:**

> JqlQuery query = QueryBuilder.anyDomainObject().build();
>   Changes javers_changes = javers.findChanges( query );

**Throws**

> org.javers.common.exception.JaversException: SQL_EXCEPTION: ORA-00920: invalid relational operator
>   while executing sql: SELECT a.*, rownum FROM (    SELECT state, type, version, changed_properties, managed_type, commit_pk, author, commit_date, commit_date_instant, commit_id, g.local_id, g.fragment, g.owner_id_fk, o.local_id owner_local_id, o.fragment owner_fragment, o.type_name owner_type_name FROM jv_snapshot INNER JOIN jv_commit ON commit_pk = commit_fk INNER JOIN jv_global_id g ON g.global_id_pk = global_id_fk LEFT OUTER JOIN jv_global_id o ON o.global_id_pk = g.owner_id_fk WHERE 1 = 1 and (  false) ORDER BY snapshot_pk DESC ) a WHERE rownum <= ?
>       at org.javers.repository.sql.session.PreparedStatementExecutor.wrapExceptionAndCall(PreparedStatementExecutor.java:128) ~[javers-persistence-sql-5.1.2.jar!/:na]
>       at org.javers.repository.sql.session.PreparedStatementExecutor.runSql(PreparedStatementExecutor.java:100) ~[javers-persistence-sql-5.1.2.jar!/:na]
>       at 
>   ...

The database configuration as read and shown by the application on startup:

> 2019-01-22 19:07:54.125  INFO 13270 --- [           main] o.j.s.b.sql.JaversSqlAutoConfiguration   : detected Hibernate dialect: Oracle10gDialect
>   2019-01-22 19:07:54.133  INFO 13270 --- [           main] o.j.repository.sql.SqlRepositoryBuilder  : starting SqlRepository...
>   2019-01-22 19:07:54.133  INFO 13270 --- [           main] o.j.repository.sql.SqlRepositoryBuilder  :   dialect:                 ORACLE
>   2019-01-22 19:07:54.133  INFO 13270 --- [           main] o.j.repository.sql.SqlRepositoryBuilder  :   schemaManagementEnabled: false
>   2019-01-22 19:07:54.134  INFO 13270 --- [           main] o.j.repository.sql.SqlRepositoryBuilder  :   schemaName:              null

My database is ORACLE and accepts Oracle/PLSQL commands. No error occurs when Javers commit data, however JQL commands appear to always fail. 
Analysing the generate sql I have found out that the problems are:

> SELECT a.*, rownum FROM (    SELECT state, type, version, changed_properties, managed_type, commit_pk, author, commit_date, commit_date_instant, commit_id, g.local_id, g.fragment, g.owner_id_fk, o.local_id owner_local_id, o.fragment owner_fragment, o.type_name owner_type_name FROM jv_snapshot INNER JOIN jv_commit ON commit_pk = commit_fk INNER JOIN jv_global_id g ON g.global_id_pk = global_id_fk LEFT OUTER JOIN jv_global_id o ON o.global_id_pk = g.owner_id_fk WHERE 1 = 1 and (  false) ORDER BY snapshot_pk DESC ) a WHERE rownum <= ?

- PL/SQL doesn't accept 'false' as it appears on WHERE;
- The character '?' isn't accepted;

Is this dialect not accepted or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: I don't know *Javers* and stuff. However, what is that `(false)` you used? If query literally looks like that, then yes - it is invalid. If it is some kind of a *Boolean* (FALSE), then the query doesn't make sense because WHERE won't return anything - it behaves like `select * from emp where 1 = 2` (here, `1 = 2` would be that "false") so I suppose that I'm wrong about it. Anyway: just to make sure, remove both `(false)` and substitute `?` with some number (1, for example) and see what happens.

Comment: This query is generated by Javers. The framework has a query builder.

Answer (score 1):

OK, so, the code you have pasted is not a PL/SQL nor SQL. It's a JDBC PreparedStatement code which looks like SQL but it has `?` placeholders.
So don't worry about `?`, they are fine.

The real problem could be caused by this tricky predicate `WHERE 1 = 1 and ( false)` which is generated by JaVers, and which probably is not a valid SQL in Oracle dialect.

Please report it here https://github.com/javers/javers/issues
we will fix it.

Comment: It looks that the entire WHERE clause is incorrect. Different queries always have the same *"WHERE 1 = 1 and (false)"*.

Answer (score 0):

This bug is fixed in Javers 5.2.6, see https://github.com/javers/javers/issues/796